# What is a "measurable function" in laymen words? (Edit: from a real analysis view)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) mentions

> In mathematics and in particular measure theory, a measurable function is a function between the underlying sets of two measurable spaces that preserves the structure of the spaces: the preimage of any measurable set is measurable, analogous to the definition that a function between topological spaces is continuous if it preserves the topological structure: the preimage of each open set is open.

However, this is not intuitive/understandable enough for someone who does not have the background in measure theory and real analysis. (For example questions below arise: What is an underlying set of measurable spaces? or What is a measurable set?)

Considering this, can someone please explain, **in easy words**, what kind of functions are measurable and what kinds are not? Some examples of both sides and highlighting the main characteristic of such functions could be helpful. Being very precise is not the goal here.

Comment: A [Measurable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space) is "a set $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$, which defines the subsets that will be measured." The "underlying set" is the set $X$.

Comment: A [Sigma-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) on a set $X$ is "is a collection of subsets of $X$ that includes $X$ itself, etc." Thus, a "measurable set" is a subset of $X$ thst is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$. This means that to it (the measurable set) its is associated a "number" : its measure.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks but I am not looking for jargon or technicalities about the components of the sentence above. I am looking for a wholistic simple explanation in English words.

Comment: Are you trying to get intuition for real analysis or probability theory? The answer is different in these cases in my view even though the mathematical definition is the same.

Comment: @Ian this is an excellent question! I am from machine learning background and have seen measurable functions in risk minimization context. Not super sure which one of the two would be the most relevant. But let's begin with real analysis. :)  (Since that is typically easier to get than probability).

Comment: On the real line (underlying space) a measurable set might be an interval. Its (Lebesgue) measure is its length. Countable Unions and intersections, complements etc of such intervals are also measurable - this is your sigma algebra. A function f from the real to the reals is measurable when $f^{-1}$ of a measurable set is also measurable. e.g $f(x) =x^2$ takes the inverse image of the measurable interval [1,4] to the union of [-2,-1] and [1, 2], a measurable set. Non-measurable sets/functions are difficult to construct and rely on the axioms of set theory to posit their existence.

Comment: In real analysis measurable functions are pretty much arbitrary functions. This isn't obvious from the definition, and in fact the details are sensitive to foundational issues, but for practical purposes you can think of it that way. In real analysis you will essentially never see a nonmeasurable set or function "in the wild".

Comment: It is not "jargon". Mathematics is made of **definitions**.

Comment: In very simple words, the collection of polygons in the plane with the "usual" area. This is a measurable space with its measure. Tha's all... if you are not studying mathematics but are only interested in laymen examples.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA! That is helping. Now what can make a polygon having unusual area? A form of discontinuity, for example?

Comment: If you're going to start hunting for even slight pathology, it helps to actually use the definitions that the community has settled on, if they exist (which in this and many other cases they do).

Comment: @Ian Is it because the underlying cause of pathology in the pathological cases is hard to explain without the definitions? Eg it is not something simple, like discontinuity?

Comment: In this particular situation you simply misunderstood Mauro ALLEGRANZA because their statement was intentionally vague. But really we have definitions in part to cleanly deal with pathology, either by defining things in the right way that we can deal with it or by defining things so that pathology is excluded. In measure theory we ostensibly went the second way (we only handle measurable sets and forget about nonmeasurable sets), but most of the time it winds up feeling more like we went the first way (because nonmeasurable sets "essentially" don't exist in the setting of real analysis).

Comment: The way I think about it, nearly everything except some really pathological sets are measurable in affine spaces.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked: "Now what can make a polygon not having "usual" area? A form of discontinuity, for example?" instead of what I asked a couple of comments above. Otherwise, it is helpful to highlight what is the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been commented, a measurable space is a set together with a collection of subsets that are declared measurable.  If that sounds a bit arbitrary, it's because it is; it's not without precedent however since a topological space is a set together with a collection of sets that are declared open.  The thing is, is that this is the simplest structure you can impose and get a rich and meaningful theory out of it -- which might seem a bit surprising when you consider how little was said.

We add more structure by defining a measure: this is a function that assigns a number to a measurable set.  It has to follow two rules (always; these are axioms, or unbreakable rules):

1. The empty set is assigned the value $0$ (which makes sense, the empty set is, in layman's terms, "nothing")
2. The whole is never less than the sum of the parts: if you take three sets and measure them and add their measures together, then the value you get is not less than what you get by measuring all three sets as though they were one.  This is called *subadditivity*.

A measurable function is one that preserves measurable sets: i.e. if $f$ is a measurable function, and you have a measurable set $f(B)$ then it must always be the case that the set of all points that $f$ maps into $f(B)$ is measurable as well.  (That's what the quote you provide is talking about when it mentions pre-images).  The guarantee is that if you have a measurable set given by $f$ then it came from a measurable set to begin with.

So what do measurable sets and functions look like?  Some examples:

1. Let $X$ be a finite set, say $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and let *every* subset of $X$ be measurable (then $X$ has a discrete measure structure).  We define $f$ as counting measure: $f(A) = \#A$ so that $f$ counts the number of elements in the set $A\subseteq X$.
2. Take all rectangles in ${\mathbb R}^2$ and define $f(R) = $width$\times$height for a rectangle. (This would be called *Jordan measure* though Jordan measure can be more complicated).
3. Take all shapes that can be approximated from the inside by rectangles (e.g. pick a triangle and draw the largest rectangle you can completely inside it.  Then in the spaces left, draw the largest rectangles you can, and repeat until there is "no space left" -- this is a limiting process so you can't physically do it).  This gives us an *inner* measure (because it's done by drawing shapes inside).  If we do it with rectangles outside the shape then we get an *outer* measure.  If the inner and outer measures give the same answer, we have *Lebesgue* measure.

So this sounds easy, where's the catch?  That would lie in:

1. there is no *ideal* measure -- for whatever you're doing one measure might be better than another (compare counting measure and Lebesgue measure above: one is good for finite sets, the other for infinite sets).
2. alongside there being no ideal measure, there are sets that cannot be measured (the *Vitali* set is a famous example of such a set).  So any function mapping the Vitali set into a measurable space cannot be measurable, because the pre-image is the Vitali set, which is not measurable.

So to your final question: whether a function is measurable or not depends entirely on the spaces you define it on and what measure-structure they have.  For most things you'll encounter outside of measure theory your functions will be measurable.

Comment: "If $f$ is a measurable function and you have a measurable set $f(B)$ then it must always be the case that $B$ is measurable as well." This is false, though it is true if $f$ is a measurable *bijection*. Here is a counterexample: Let $S \subseteq [0,1]$ be an unmeasurable set, and define $\pi_2 : [0,1]^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$ to be the usual projection: $\pi_2(x,y) = y$. Now, $S \times \{0\} \subseteq [0,1]^2$ is not measurable, but $\pi_2(S \times \{0\}) = \{0\}$, which *is* measurable.

Comment: The correct statement is "A measurable function is a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ such that for each measurable set $B \subseteq Y$ the set $f^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in B \}$ is measurable."

Comment: @RobertFurber thanks!  I've tried to make that clearer in the text without deviating from using easy terms, as per OP's request.